# the image is not showing up

Tags: html, jquery, image

The images in the directory `training_images/class1` are frame 0 to 99.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i){                         
   $("#class1-images").prepend($('<img>',{id:'theImg',src:'training_images/class1/frame' + i + ".jpg"})                             
)}
```

So when I run this code, I do not see the images.

I need the images to be displayed.
I tried dragging the image into google chrome, and copied the path from there and pasted the URL in my code, but it's still not working.

Comment: Do you get any errors on the console? Can you show us a screenshot of your project's files, so we can see if the path is correct? Also, notice this would create man images, all with the same ID, which isn't a good thing

Comment: Show your html code

Comment: @Sri Rama Punniya Vallabhar please approve any of the answers mentioned or comment if it doesn't suffice your needs. This will help the community to identify the helpful one!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select a tag `<img>` which doesn't exist. `$` is a jQuery function equivalent to `document.querySelector()`. Therefore, to select the `img` tag you simply need to replace the `<img>` → `img`. This is all what can be interpreted from the code provided by you!

Final Code Compilation:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i){                         
   $("#class1-images").prepend($('img',{id:'theImg',src:'training_images/class1/frame' + i + ".jpg"})                             
)}
```

Comment: *$ is a jQuery function equivalent to document.querySelector()* - no, no it's not.

Comment: Your code will take an existing `<img>` tag and move it 100 times => still one image tag.  OPS code *should* create 100 new image tags because `$("<div>")` create new HTML content, not `querySelector` existing ones.  See Carsten's snippet, then make your code into a snippet and run it.

Comment: I don't know their exact expectations since it wasn't clearly mentioned. Simply intended to find the flaw in the existing code.

Comment: @freedomn-m have you gotten it all wrong? `$` = `.querySelector()`
https://api.jquery.com/jquery/

Comment: Scroll down a bit further to https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes : `jQuery( html [, ownerDocument ] )` *Creates DOM elements on the fly from the provided string of raw HTML* ... *If a string is passed as the parameter to $()... jQuery attempts to create new DOM elements as described by the HTML* - can't see doc.querySelector doing that...

Comment: Also `$(function()...` - see  https://api.jquery.com/ready/#ready-handler - can't see doc.querySelector doing that either.    `$ = .querySelector()` is in the browser console when jquery is *not* defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your script should work - provided the target element exists and there are images behind the added URLs:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i){                         
   $("#class1-images").prepend($('<img>',{id:'theImg',src:`https://picsum.photos/id/${i}/200/150`})                             
)}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="class1-images"></div>
```